# Where do I Place the ORDER BY in this statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out where to place the ORDER BY statement below... Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Load all products
$ProdPackQ = "SELECT prod_name AS Name, days_span, CONCAT(LEFT(prodID,2),ID) AS ID,     geo_targeting FROM products WHERE status = 'Active' AND vendID = ".$resort['vendID'];
if(isset($_GET['dz']))
$ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = ".$_GET['dz'];
/*else
$ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = 1"; */
$ProdPackQ .= " AND prod_type = ".$thisprodtype;
if(count($packarr) != 0)

{ $ProdPackQ .= " UNION SELECT pack_name AS Name, days_span, CONCAT(LEFT(packID,2),ID), NULL as geo_targeting FROM packages WHERE ID IN(".$mypacks.")";
    if(isset($_GET['dz']))
    $ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = ".$_GET['dz'];
/*else
    $ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = 1"; */
$ProdPackQ .= " ORDER BY prod_name, days_span, ID";
}
```

Comment: You've put it right. Do you experience any issues with it? But you can only order by selected fields

Comment: I'd place it outside of the `if(count($packarr)!=0)` block.

Comment: when I uncomment the //print $ProdPackQ; the Order BY is not in the SQL statement

Comment: @user949509: see mysql errors with `mysql_error()`

Comment: should I try $ProdPackQ .= " ORDER BY prod_name" ?

Comment: @user949509: have you read my previous comment?

Comment: placing it outside the "if(count($packarr)!=0) block. – bdares" worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORDER BY is in the right place, but you need it in the select like this

```
// Load all products
$ProdPackQ = "SELECT prod_name AS Name, days_span, CONCAT(LEFT(prodID,2),ID) AS ID,                 
geo_targeting FROM products WHERE status = 'Active' AND vendID = ".$resort['vendID'];
if(isset($_GET['dz']))
$ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = ".$_GET['dz'];
/*else
$ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = 1"; */
$ProdPackQ .= " AND prod_type = ".$thisprodtype;
if(count($packarr) != 0)

{ $ProdPackQ .= " UNION SELECT pack_name AS Name, days_span, CONCAT(LEFT(packID,2),ID) AS ID,      
 NULL as geo_targeting FROM packages WHERE ID IN(".$mypacks.")";
    if(isset($_GET['dz']))
     $ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = ".$_GET['dz'];
/*else
$ProdPackQ .= " AND days_span = 1"; */
$ProdPackQ .= " ORDER BY Name, days_span, ID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the rule thumb is put order by in the last part of your query. so put it outside of your if block of statement.